# Add existing source files to netbeans

Tags: git, netbeans

I have a git repository cloned to my computer. I would like to open that project in netbeans. However, when choosing to open an existing project within netbeans and going to the directory where my project is, the folder is empty. In other words there are no source files to add. I would like to open this project in netbeans. How can I do this without creating a new project and copying and pasting code?

Comment: You don't go to the project folder but to the parent folder and as project select the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

did you pull the repo to local folder? If the folder is empy, it looks like you didn't do that yet.

Make sure you pull the repo to the local disc that should fill the folder. Next, open netbeans and setup a new project with existing source and point NB to the git folder you've just filled.

Comment: Yes I pulled the repo to the local folder. It is on the local disk. I just want to add the source files to netbeans, but I guess because there is no netbeans make file, I can't open those files using open existing project. I can point to those files using add existing files option, but that does not accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to File | Open Project and select the directory with the pom.xml
NetBeans, unlike eclipse or idea doesn't need any command to create project files.